# error: tipa in combination with \DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mathtools, tipa

I would like to use phonetic spelling and found the `tipa` package. Somehow it seems to produce an error combined with a command I use to set conditional probability distributions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs,mathtools} 

% conditional distribution
\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\condition[1]{}{}{}{}{%
    \renewcommand\given{  \nonscript\:
        \delimsize\vert
        \nonscript\:
        \mathopen{}
        \allowbreak}
    #1
}

\usepackage{tipa}              


\begin{document}
$\condition{X\given Y}$.    
\end{document}
```

> Undefined control sequence. \ttl@finishall
>
> Missing { inserted. $\condition{X\given Y}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is of course different (the one you mention is linked to `titlesec` and happens when you remove the call to the package). You get, instead,

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \: invalid in math mode on input line 19.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.19 $\condition{X\given Y}
                           $.
```

What happens is that `tipa` redefines `\:`. You have two strategies:

1. Use `\nonscript\mskip\medmuskip` instead of `\nonscript\:`
2. Load `tipa` with the `safe` option, that doesn't redefine `\:`, `\;` and `\!`

For more information about the `safe` option, look at section 3.2.4 in the manual of `tipa`.